# Realm+Swift: Suggestion for "live filtering" of Results

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, realm

I'm trying to create an (iOS) app that can query a set of objects from Realm, allowing the user to search and incrementally updating a UITableView. I initially thought I would change the filter on my Realm Results instance, but changing / chaining a new filter returns a *new* Results instance. The result is that I will have to tell my UITableView to reload (which I'd like to avoid if possible, as I'm currently using Realm notifications—on the Results instance—to get fine-grained updates in the tableview).

Any suggestions for how to go about creating a "live updating" Results object where the filter criteria can be changed "on the fly"? Or am I stuck with the "change Results instance and reload entire table" approach?

Answer (score 0):

Realm `Results` is a view per-query. If the predicate of the query changes, it is the right way to retrieve a new `Results` and reload the table view. I think incremental search changes the query predicate every user's input, so live query doesn't work, you need to re-create predicates and results every user input.